# Self hosted Wcf serves wsdl but 404's when invoked

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to self-host a singleton instance of a service and I'm obviously getting lost at a level of indirection...

I've got a base address of `http://localhost:8050/`. I'm not too bothered where the service endpoint is as long as it's predictable. For the moment, I'm trying to use `/Manage/`.

I'm able to browse to the base address and see a wsdl. If I scan through the wsdl, it points at `/Manage/`..

```
<wsdl:service name="EngineService">
    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IEngineService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IEngineService">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:8050/Manage/"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

When I consume the wsdl using the [WcfTestClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it lists all the correct methods, but calling any of them throw the following exception

> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:8050/Manage that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IEngineService.SupportedAgents()
   at EngineServiceClient.SupportedAgents()

Inner Exception:
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
```

Log messages show my instance methods never get called. The service doesn't enter a faulted state, it just looks like it's not there.

I'm listening as follows:

```
    public static ServiceHost Listen<TServiceContract>(
            TServiceContract instance,
            int port,
            string name
        ) {

        //Added this for debugging, was previously just "name"
        string endpoint = String.Format("http://localhost:{0}/{1}/", port, name);

        var svcHost = new ServiceHost(
            instance,
            new Uri[] { new Uri(String.Format("http://localhost:{0}/", port)) });

        /* Snip: Add a Faulted handler but it's never called */

        ServiceEndpoint serviceHttpEndpoint = svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
            typeof(TServiceContract),
            new BasicHttpBinding {
                HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.WeakWildcard
            }, endpoint); /*Using name instead of endpoint makes no difference beyond removing the trailing slash */

        /* Snip: Add a ServiceDebugBehavior with IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true */
        /* Snip: Add a ServiceMetadataBehavior with HttpGetEnabled = true */

        try {
            log.Trace("Opening endpoint");
            svcHost.Open();
        } catch () {
            /* Lots of catches for different problems including Exception
             * None of them get hit */
        }


        log.Info("Service contract {0} ready at {1}", typeof(TServiceContract).Name, svcHost.BaseAddresses.First());
        return svcHost;
```

And calling the `Listen()` method as follows:

```
        IEngineService wcfInstance = Resolver.Resolve<IEngineService>();
        service = WcfHoster.Listen(wcfInstance, 8050, "Manage");
```

How can I track down what the problem is/debug further?

Additional info: The Service contract and minimal implementation:

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IEngineService {
    [OperationContract]
    List<string> Agents();

    [OperationContract]
    string Test();

    [OperationContract]
    List<string> SupportedAgents();

    [OperationContract]
    string Connect(string AgentStrongName, string Hostname);
}
```

And the implementation:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
class EngineService : IEngineService {
    IAgentManager agentManager;
    public EngineService(IAgentManager AgentManager) {
        log.Debug("Engine webservice instantiating");
        this.agentManager = AgentManager;
    }

    public string Connect(string AgentStrongName, string Hostname) {
        log.Debug("Endpoint requested for [{0}], [{1}]", Hostname, AgentStrongName);
        return agentManager.GetSession(AgentStrongName, Hostname);
    }

    public List<string> Agents() {
        log.Debug("Current agents queried");
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public List<string> SupportedAgents() {
        log.Debug("Supported agents queried");
        return agentManager.SupportedAgents().ToList();
    }

    public string Test() {
        log.Warn("Test query");
        return "Success!";
    }
}
```

The test client can see the service and methods but throws the exception above when I click Invoke...

[image]

Edit: localhost resolves to IPv6 by default so I've tried using 127.0.0.1 explicitly at both ends. No difference.

I've tried taking the above code into a new project and get the same issue. Running the whole thing on someone else's machine didn't help either.

#### Service Trace viewer

Running a [service trace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751795(v=vs.110).aspx) on the server side, then examining the results in the viewer gives:

> Failed to lookup a channel to receive an incoming message. Either the endpoint or the SOAP action was not found.

[image]

Config file: Since I need the executable to be able to make a decision about which Wcf service to present at runtime, I don't have any Wcf-related code in the config file.

Comment: what line of code does your exception happen?

Comment: In the client consuming the service, not the process hosting service itself, hence my difficulty debugging

Comment: Could you please be more specific like in the try catch or somewhere else?

Comment: My actual catch has blocks for `CommunicationObjectFaultedException`, `TimeoutException` and `Exception`. None of them get hit. As far as I can tell from the host process, the service is loading fine, serving wsdl, etc... It's just that when any method is called, I get a 404 in the client. As far as I can tell, the host doesn't even see that call. The exception message I'm showing is from the Wcf Test Client that comes with Visual Studio to test consuming web services. If you can clarify what you'd like caught, I'll add a try/catch

Comment: Well your code looks fine, I'm just guessing that something is wrong with svcHost? I don't know what else possibly could be wrong.

Comment: That's why I'm confused too. I've even tried using curl to POST a valid SOAP packet and I see a 404 there too. I've set url acl's to allow the endpoints to be used, I've turned on error reporting in the service, and I've got `log.Trace()` calls everywhere. As far as I can tell, the request to the service never gets handed to any of my code, so something's returning a 404 at a more fundamental level? I don't even know how to debug that

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you any further. Please let me know when you fixed it :) and good luck.

Comment: @Giulio Thanks for the suggestion, I'll have a read through and see if it applies. Re: NotImplementedExceptions, I simply haven't got as far as implementing `AgentManager.CurrentAgents()`, but wanted to ensure that I can actually call the service before diving too deep into the implementation.

Comment: @Giulio no Web.config as this is a console app (eventually an NT service). No App.config that mentions WCF as I'm trying to do it all in code. The reason for that is to allow the executable to make a decision about which service to load at runtime (first instance presents a Management API which can be used to spawn agent processes with their own agent-specific API). So management service will accept class full names, look in specific assemblies for the class, spawn an agent process and pass that name and an endpoint through the command line, then return the new endpoint. Is that clearer?

Comment: I tried out this same code and it is working fine in my machine. Hosted using a console application. Is there any firewall setting for port 8050 that block communication from test client?

Comment: Have you check if the constructor of EngineService ever gets called? So is wcfInstance not null? I tried to reconstruct this on my own and if get have an instance of EngineService is works fine. Running into problems when I pass `null` though. But have to add I used a parameterless constructor for EngineService then he builds up his own instance if you pass `null`...

Comment: Also, your `App.config` does not contain any `<system.serviceModel>` element?

Comment: Correct, no system.servicemodel in the config file at all. Yes, the wcfInstance is definitely instantiated successfully, I can call methods on it manually (in fact, that's how I'm continuing development while I solve this...). @user3176048 Interesting data point, thanks! I've added firewall exceptions so colleagues can see the problem. They're able to fetch Wsdl. Also, the trace was of the _host_ process so calls were definitely reaching it. Any chance I could ask you to zip up that test project and share a link? Would allow me to copare and contrast, and might be sufficient for a solution.

Comment: I had good experience with this self hosted service template: http://webservices20.blogspot.co.il/2009/06/wcf-self-hosting-project-template.html . maybe you can try to start from it and and when it works slowly change it to the same pattern you currently use and see where it breaks.

Comment: @YaronNaveh Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. It's a good place to start from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a client / service binding mismatch. Please check the test client binding. You should also create a unit test by generating a proxy from the wsdl.

Ok. I have tried to reproduce your issue and I managed calling the host by removing "HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.WeakWildcard" in order to get a default basichttp endpoint. Why do you need this?

Comment: As mentioned in the question, the client is the WcfTestClient which is generating the config and bindings entirely from the Wsdl. The auto-generated binding's client node is as follows: `<client><endpoint address="http://localhost:8050/Manage" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="ManageWs_IEngineService" contract="IEngineService"
                name="ManageWs_IEngineService" /></client>`

Comment: Interesting, it was due to an issue where providing a BaseUri in this form: `http://*:1234/` or `http://+:1234/` in code was throwing an exception. (The methods expect `Uri[]` and the Uri class complains about an invalid hostname when using the wildcard syntax. `0.0.0.0` worked but the Wsdl used `0.0.0.0` in links which invalid. From the docs `WeakWildcard: If no strong or exact match was found, ignores the hostname when matching.`). Let me test and get back to you, thanks for the hint

Comment: Yep, removing `HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.WeakWildcard` did the trick. Thanks for your help, I hope the bounty gives you a kick-start here.

Comment: Thx, WCF is my favourite .Net technology. I hope you'll also enjoy it.